# Zero Subtotal Payment not showing in admin and frontend

Tags: configuration, payment-methods

I have activated zero subtotal payment in the configuration. And i have made sure, that it is activated for the shop (I explicitly activated it for the shop, even if it is set active globally).

But it does not show in the backend Manage->Products->(Some Product)->Prices->Disabled Payment Methods

And it is not available during checkout. I edited the `getMethods()` method from `Mage_Payment_Block_Form_Container` to log the available payment methods. And the only methods returned are: debit, bankpayment and invoice.

Furthermore i did a diff of the core/Mage/Payment folder with the source of Magento 1.7.0.2 and have found no differences.

Has anyone an idea, what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try clearing var/cache and check after that if you haven't already.

Also  Manage->Products->(Some Product)->Prices->Disabled Payment Methods is not really default Magento behavior.

It could be that some custom extension makes that possible so maybe disable that extension and check then.

Comment: This did not work.

Comment: Have made an edit to the answer.

Comment: Thanks. That is the solution. I have an extension from RicoNeizel called Payment Filter. This causes all the trouble. There is a solution postet at: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards%20/viewthread/54441/ I mark your answer as right.

Comment: paras,is Disabled Payment Methods exit on default magento??

Comment: @Amit - Nope, it doesn't.